# Sum of largest two angles

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

All the inner angles of a 7 sided polygon are obtuse, their sizes in degrees being distinct integers divisible by 9. What is the sum (in degree) of the largest two angles?

Comment: You know the possible sizes of an obtuse angle if it's divisible by 9; you know the sum of the angles of a 7-sided polygon; can you work out something about the sizes of the individual angles? You're expected to at least have a go at a problem you post here, not just dump it here without putting any thought into it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum of all angles is $180^\circ \cdot (n-2) = 900^\circ$.

Denote angles as $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ ($a<b<c<d<e<f<g$).

If all angles are obtuse and are integer numbers divisible by $9^\circ$, then they can be 
$99^\circ, 108^\circ, 117^\circ, 126^\circ, 135^\circ, 144^\circ, 153^\circ, ...$

**A).** 
If $a\ge 108^\circ$, then $b\ge 117^\circ, c\ge 126^\circ, d\ge 135^\circ, \ldots$, then 
$a+b+c+d+e+f+g\ge (108+117+126+135+144+153+162)^\circ = 945^\circ>900^\circ.$

So, $a=99^\circ$.

**B).**
If $b\ge 117^\circ$, then $c\ge 126^\circ$, $\ldots$, then
$a+b+c+d+e+f+g\ge (99+117+126+135+144+153+162)^\circ= 936^\circ>900^\circ$.

So, $b=108^\circ$.

**C).**
Same way we can show, that $c=117^\circ$,  ...

After that you can find possible values for $2$ largest angles.

Comment: According to the options to this question given in my book I found the largest angles to be 153 and 162 and thus answer is 315 degrees.

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR, yes, answer is $315^\circ$. It can be $153^\circ+162^\circ$, and $144^\circ+171^\circ$.